# How to play background audio in iOS with Trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I'm attempting to build a streaming audio application with Trigger.io's framework.

Seeing that its API currently does not feature any audio-related methods, I tested it with basic HTML5 `audio` tags. Streaming MP3 and AAC worked in this case, but not when the application is backgrounded, even in iOS 5, which typically allows background audio in web apps.

Is there any to background audio in a Trigger.io application?

Answer (score 4):

**Update, April 2013:** We added a native audio playback API on our v1.4.39 platform: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/media.html#createaudioplayer

Using this API, audio will continue to play when the user changes focus from the app.

---

**Original answer:**

Trigger doesn't yet support background audio playback.

The device manufacturers (rightly!) put some restrictions on being able to do work as a background service: we've not yet linked together starting and controlling playback in your JavaScript, with the non-JavaScript code that would actually *do* the playing.

It's on our roadmap, however: currently scheduled for completion in May 2012.

Comment: I'm afraid not: we've not had much customer interest in this feature compared to other things on the roadmap, so we've de-prioritised this over the last month or two.

Comment: So what is currently on list ?