# Is it possible to control iTunes from an app (to make it play a paused song)?

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, trigger.io, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm looking at the [MPMusicPlayerController class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221), which lets you create an `iPodMusicPlayer` with a [playbackState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221) that is **readonly**. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to modify the playbackState elsewhere to change the state from `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused` to `MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying`.

The goal if this is to play iTunes music which is paused by the [TriggerIO media player](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/media.html#createaudioplayer) — currently it supports playing audio in your app by pausing background audio, but after my audio plays, I want to continue playing the background audio.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking to do something more like an overlay, like Maps does. The player is assuming you want to actually play a song, which does not imply resuming a different apps player once yours is done.

Comment: An app can control a song that is playing in iTunes.  I know this because I have an app on my iPhone called "Car Tunes" that can be used to control the song that is currently playing.  If pause a song with the built in "Music" app, I can unpause it with Car Tunes and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I'm turning my comment into an answer because if found a bit more proof.

My assumption is that you're looking for something like background audio, or an audio overlay. Which, according to, [How to play background audio in iOS with Trigger.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400201/how-to-play-background-audio-in-ios-with-trigger-io), which was answered by a co-founder of trigger.io, it is not officially supported yet, but on their roadmap.

Comment: Yes, I've been in contact with the founders but their current implementation is unfortunately all there will be for a while (at least that's how it looks), so I'm looking for a native way to do it that I can just put into a native plugin. I am, as you guessed, looking for the same effect as the Google Maps voiceovers.